# como imprimir un echo en una pagina principal

Tags: php, mysql

alguien me puede ayudar quisiera que los mensaje echo me aparezcan debajo de mi formulario para que no me manden a otro pagina, este es mi código.

```html
<?php

require ("conexion.php");

$nombre= $_POST ['nombre'];
$correo= $_POST ['correo'];
$contrasena= $_POST ['contrasena'];
$contrasena2= $_POST ['contrasena2'];

$contrasena = hash('sha512', $contrasena);
$contrasena2 = hash('sha512', $contrasena2);

$fecha = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S", time()); 

$error= '';

if (empty($correo) or empty($nombre) or empty($contrasena) or empty($contrasena2)){
 echo "favor de llenar todos los datos";
}else{

if ($contrasena != $contrasena2){
 echo "Las contraseñas no coinciden";
}else{



$repetir= mysqli_query($conexionmysqli,"SELECT COUNT(0) AS total FROM usuarios WHERE correo='$correo'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_object($repetir);
if($row->total > 0){
 echo "correo repetido";

}else{
 
$consulta= "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, correo, contrasena, fecha) VALUES ('$nombre','$correo','$contrasena','$fecha') ";

$resultado= mysqli_query ($conexionmysqli, $consulta);

if ($resultado==false) {
 echo "error en la consulta";

}else {
 echo "Registro guardado";

}
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Daniel bienvenido. No entiendo tu pregunta. Hablas de un formulario, pero ¿dónde está ese formulario? Parece que estás trabajando con Ajax, pero no muestras el código que envía los datos al servidor. Es ahí donde debes trabajar para que no te mande a otra página.

Answer (score 0):

(PHP & MYSQL) Para que los "ECHOS" queden debajo del formulario, una solución fácil sería agregar el formulario encima del código de PHP, y el documento debe estar con la extensión ".php". Es decir,tu código debería quedar más o menos así:

INDEX.PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="index.php" method="POST">
  nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre"><br/>
  email: <input type="email" name="correo"><br/>
  contraseña: <input type="password" name="contrasena"><br/>
  confirmar contraseña: <input type="password" name="contrasena1"><br/> 
 </form>
</body>
</html>


<?php

 require ("conexion.php");

 $nombre= $_POST ['nombre'];
 $correo= $_POST ['correo'];
 $contrasena= $_POST ['contrasena'];
 $contrasena2= $_POST ['contrasena2'];

 $contrasena = hash('sha512', $contrasena);
 $contrasena2 = hash('sha512', $contrasena2);

 $fecha = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S", time()); 

 $error= '';

 if (empty($correo) or empty($nombre) or empty($contrasena) or empty($contrasena2)){
    echo "favor de llenar todos los datos";
 }else{

  if ($contrasena != $contrasena2){
    echo "Las contraseñas no coinciden";
  }else{



  $repetir= mysqli_query($conexionmysqli,"SELECT COUNT(0) AS total FROM usuarios 
            WHERE correo='$correo'"); 
  $row=mysqli_fetch_object($repetir);
  if($row->total > 0){
  echo "correo repetido";

  }else{

  $consulta= "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, correo, contrasena, fecha) VALUES 
  ('$nombre','$correo','$contrasena','$fecha') ";

  $resultado= mysqli_query ($conexionmysqli, $consulta);

  if ($resultado==false) {
    echo "error en la consulta"; 
  }else {
    echo "Registro guardado";
  }
 }
 }
 }
?>
```